# XNA - How to "install" Lidgren?

Tags: c#, xna, multiplayer, lidgren

How do I use [Lidgren.Network](http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/)? I mean, "install" it so I can use it in my project? Because I would love to get started with simple multiplayer games, but I can't find any good tutorials online, but I've heard that Lidgren.Network is good :D

I tried to just drag the Lidgren.Network into the project, but I couldn't use it that way, I guess it was a really bad idea..

And also, if I make a game using Lidgren.Network for networking, will I be able to sell it? And if not, will I be able to upload it at all?

Comment: You add the DLLs to list of references and then you can call its methods.

Comment: Oh, thanks x) Also, do you know anything about the license part?

Comment: Well, did you read it? I think there already exists a question about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `Lidgren.dll` as a reference to your project. Take a look at the picture below (Made in VS 2012, but same for any other editions)

[image: http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/9701/nbub.png]

Hit browse and find your Lidgren dll.

This is not the place for legal advice, so don't tank us in the place of a lawyer, but as you can see on the [homepage](http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/), it is under a [MIT](http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php) license.

> ... including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify,
>   merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the
>   Software...

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry :/  But the only download avaliable on the site was a .zip file with a couple solutions and classes?

Comment: What is this site? The official google code page/project is here: http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/

Comment: That's the site, it's a .zip files with samples only D:

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/zeUROxQ.png) is what is in my file, which I just downloaded. Open the project file and build it. The `.dll` should be outputted to the `\Lidgren.Network\bin` folder.

Comment: Oh that solves it all, thanks Cyral :D  I'm curious, what does the .pdb file do? Is it important? :)

Comment: It's just used for debugging, no need for it.

Comment: @QuackTheDuck: Also you can click that nice little green check up there since this solved it (Not trying to be pushy just wasn't sure if you were aware of it) :P

Comment: Haha, i know^^ But i just wanted to make sure everything worked. Thanks once again :D